# Iterate a JObject

Tags: c#, angularjs

I send this to the web api as Json string  Question: How iterate and get values for each Array, Object Array  and Object?

```
generateQMEPanelRequest(date: Array<any>, text: Array<string>, checkboxes: Array<number>, personserved: IPersonServed[], qme31_7: IQme31_7): ng.IPromise<any> {
                var data = {
                    Date: date,
                    Text: text,
                    CheckBox: checkboxes,
                    PersonServed: personserved,
                    QQME_31_7: qme31_7
                };
              return this.$http.post('/api/ClientForms/QMEPanelRequest',data).then(this.handleSuccess, this.handleError);
```

on the Web api I get the model as Jobject:

```
Model   {{
  "Date": [
    "2017-04-03T07:00:00Z",
    "2017-04-10T07:00:00Z",
    "2017-06-13T07:00:00Z"
  ],
  "Text": [
    "mam",
    "5445",
    "MDE Dermatology"
  ],
  "CheckBox": [
    "1",
    "4"
  ],
  "PersonServed": [
    {
      "personId": 1,
      "method": "B",
      "name": "dd",
      "address": "d",
      "city": "d",
      "state": "d",
      "zipCode": "d",
      "$$hashKey": "object:674"
    }
  ],
  "QQME_31_7": {
    "recordsOfFirstName": "a",
    "recordsOfMI": "a",
    "recordsOfLastName": "dd",
    "caseNo": "d",
    "ownerAddress": "ddd",
    "ownerState": "dd",
    "ownerZip": "d"
  }
}}  


  public IHttpActionResult QMEPanelRequest(JObject data)
        {
```

How iterate and get values for each Array, Object Array  and Object?

Comment: Could you please post the JSON object as a text rather than image?

Comment: did you read their [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm) ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
                JArray Date = (JArray)data["Date"];
                JArray Text = (JArray)data["Text"];
                JArray CheckBox = (JArray)data["CheckBox"];
                JArray PersonServed = (JArray)data["PersonServed"];
```